# Inline form design with bootstrap in asp.net content page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webforms

Hi everyone I am new with bootstrap. I have been using a bootstrap template in my asp.net web form project. I am done with master page. Now i have been designing a content page. The content page will contain an Inline Form like bellow image:

[image: Content Page Form]

As I am new with bootstrap I do not know how I can do this and what CSS class should i use. Can anyone give my some sample.

**My Master Page Code is given bellow:**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.Master.cs" Inherits="CJDMS.Website.Master" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server" role="form">        
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="MainScriptManager" EnablePartialRendering="true">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/js/jquery-1.10.2.js") %>'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/js/jquery-2.1.1.js") %>'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/js/jquery-ui.js") %>'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js") %>'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/js/bootstrap.min.js") %>'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js") %>'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/js/plugins/morris/raphael-2.1.0.min.js") %>'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/js/plugins/morris/morris.js") %>'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/js/sb-admin.js") %>'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/js/demo/dashboard-demo.js") %>'></script>

        <div id="wrapper">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="Default.aspx">
                        <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:JalmohalResource, AppsTitle %>" /></a>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-header -->

                <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- /.dropdown -->
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>User Profile</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i>Settings</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i>Logout</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
                    </li>
                    <!-- /.dropdown -->
                </ul>
                <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->

                <div class="navbar-default navbar-static-side " role="navigation">
                    <div class="sidebar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                            <li class="sidebar-search">
                                <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <%--<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearch" CssClass="btn btn-default" />--%>
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /input-group -->
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i>Company Profile</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i>Vehicle <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="flot.html">Bus Models</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="morris.html">Bus List</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="tables.html"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i>Fare List</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="forms.html"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i>User Management</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i>Sales Information <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="panels-wells.html">Sales By Counter</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="buttons.html">Sales By Trip</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="notifications.html">Booked By Counter</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="typography.html">Booked By Trip</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="grid.html">Summary</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i>Route Details <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Routes</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Counters</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Schedules</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Counter Schedules</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Counter Users</a>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>
                                <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i>Log Out</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /#side-menu -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
            </nav>

            <div id="page-wrapper">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <div>
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bootstrap docs illustrate how to do this very easily. First, [use the grid system.](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)
To create the top two columns you could do:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5"></div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-11"></div>
</div>
```

To make the top row equal in size to the bottom I created the bottom using an 11 size, which is smaller than the bootstrap normal 12 column width, but it does give the top two columns identical size with a gap between.

To create labels next to the form inputs, use [Horizontal Forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms). You could replace the first column with the first row like:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
     <div class="form-horizontal">
          <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Label</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" />
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Use the bootstrap docs. Bootstrap is exceptionally well documented and you should find answers to almost anything by using them.

Comment: hi thanks for solution. I have go through as you said. But there is two problem found. one if second row becomes center and there is no space between first row and second row. Please visit the following link to see the designed form and code. http://imgur.com/9NV2Dca   and http://imgur.com/YzCFAkP

Comment: Look at the row with the browser's F12 developer tools. The second row should not be centered as Bootstrap will go left to right. It could very well be that it is within a fieldset and throwing it off. Most likely you have other CSS somewhere that is interfering because bootstrap rows have spacing as shown in the Bootstrap Grid CSS examples: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid  Something else is changing the settings and most likely comes from the fieldset.